# Significant performance difference between iterator-based loop and index-based loop in C++ with SFML

Tags: c++, c++17, sfml, stdvector

I'm using SFML in C++ to develop a simple 2D grid visualization game engine. I have a Grid class with a std::vector<sf::Vertex> where each cell in the grid is represented by 6 vertices. When I update the color of each cell based on its state, I'm observing a massive performance difference between two loops: one using the iterator of the vector and the other using an index-based approach.

Here's where the difference appears:

```cpp
inline void ChangeCellColor(Cell& cell, sf::Color color)
{
    // index-based loop
    auto index = cell.grid_y * width_ + cell.grid_x;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        vertices_[index * 6 + i].color = color;
    }

    // iterator-based loop (commented out for now)
    /*
    auto index = cell.grid_y * width_ + cell.grid_x;
    for (auto it = vertices_.begin() + index * 6; it != vertices_.begin() + index * 6 + 6; ++it)
    {
        it->color = color;
    }
    */
}
```

Using the index-based loop, I achieve FPS in the range of 1150-1350. However, when I switch to the iterator-based loop, the FPS drops dramatically to 30-45.

What could be the reason behind such a drastic performance difference between the two approaches? Am I missing something about vector iterators?

Env: Visual Studio 2022, Debug build

Comment: What optimization level are you using in the compiler? What compiler is it? Iterator debugging / checked iterators performed by some library implementations can destroy performance. The compiler may also not be recognizing the loop's end condition `vertices_.begin() + index * 6 + 6` as constant and may be re-calculating it every time.

Comment: To rule out recalculation of the end condition as a performance issue, I typically implement iterator loops like this: `for (auto it = vertices_.begin() + index * 6, end = it + 6; it != end; ++it)`

Comment: In the first `for` loop, the expression `index * 6` is constant, you should calculate before the loop:  `const int row = index * 6; /*...*/ vertices[row + i].color = color;`  This should make your program faster.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews This won't make the program faster. Any half decent compiler can recognize and optimize this.

Comment: Another "assistance" to the compiler would be to make a temporary pointer whose value is `vertices[index * 6]`.  Then use expression *temporary_pointer[i]*.

Comment: @chrysante I like to give the compiler some help in optimizing.  I'm not sure the compiler would optimize the expression the way I want, but the truth is in the assembly language listing.  I have issues with compilers and their optimizations.

Comment: @paddy I am developing on Visual Studio 2022 and this was a Debug build. 
I have tried Release and it seems like there is no difference actually. So the performance difference is only visible on Debug build.

Comment: @AK-35 VS adds by default insane instrumentation to vector iterators in debug builds.  You can turn it off with a build flag.

Comment: Of what type is `vertices_`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo it is `std::vector<sf::Vertex>` and I make only one call on each frame to draw this "VertexArray" `window.draw(&vertices_[0], vertices_.size(), sf::Triangles);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are most likely falling victim to [Checked Iterators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/checked-iterators?view=msvc-170). These are notorious for performance issues when iterating over standard containers in Debug builds.

They can be disabled with the macro [_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/iterator-debug-level?view=msvc-170). You can define this macro to expand to the value `0` in your source (before including `vector`), or do it in your project settings.

I would personally define this in the project settings (C / C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions), but for a quickfire test you can do it directly in your source:

```
#define _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 0
#include <vector>

// ...

inline void ChangeCellColor(Cell& cell, sf::Color color)
{
    auto index = cell.grid_y * width_ + cell.grid_x;
    for (auto it = vertices_.begin() + index * 6, end = it + 6; it != end; ++it)
    {
        it->color = color;
    }
}
```

If you're using a typical Microsoft project with the precompiled header `stdafx.h`, you can put it in there.